# Will file system be corrupted on raw disk modification?

Tags: filesystems, disk-io

Some OSs allow programs to edit raw disk, bypassing the file system. If I'm wrong(ie only raw read is allowed, not raw write), please correct me.

If I'm correct, then what will happen if a program modifies a raw disk, modifying some blocks, but not updating the disk tables(free block list, FAT etc)? Will the file system auto update it or notify the program, get corrupted, or something else?

For example, if nothing is done, the file system may write a new file to the blocks containing those data thinking that they are currently free(if the free block list is not updated by the program).

Comment: Yes, raw write is allowed on most OSes. Common sense says that if you do so incorrectly, you'll corrupt the data on the disk, because you're doing it with raw I/O and not through normal file operations. Why would you think there's any question about that?

Comment: Even if you write the proper info to the disk the OS may still cache the data if you bypass it completely. Anything can happen.

Comment: See, for example, [How to intentionally corrupt an ext4 filesystem?](https://superuser.com/q/1019485/23257)